# Find $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}f(x)\:dx$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function satisfying:

$$\left(f(x)\right)^{99}=x-f(x) \tag{1}$$ Then Find $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}f(x)\:dx$$

My try:

Replacing $x$ with $-x$ in the functional equation we get:
$$\left(f(-x)\right)^{99}=-x-f(-x)\tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:

$$\left(f(x)\right)^{99}+\left(f(-x)\right)^{99}=-(f(x)+f(-x))$$

One solution is $$f(-x)=-f(x)$$

Any way from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Show that $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1} (x)=x^{99}+x$. Then $f(0)=0$ and
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} f(x) dx=\sqrt{3}a-\int_{0}^{a} f^{-1}(x) dx $$
where $a=f(\sqrt{3})\approx 0.9969$ is the unique solution of the equation $a^{99}=\sqrt{3}-a$.